# Jmeter response time confusion, In load testing what time do I need to consider as the response time

Tags: jmeter, postman

I am using Jmeter for performan testing, I believe elapsed time is the response time which I am considering(i.e.,85 milliseconds). When I hit the same request from postman It is taking very less time(i.e.,35 milliseconds) so I want to know where my JMETER giving correct results or not

Answer (score 0):

Elapsed time consists of:

1. [Connect time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session) (it might include [SSL handshake](https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/ssl-handshake-explained-4dabb87cdce))
2. [Latency](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0/)
3. Application response time

Given you're running the same request (URL, body, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)) from the same machine you should have similar results.

Try running the request for more times, i.e. 10 or 100 using [newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman) and JMeter (set number of iterations in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to 100). If you will still be seeing differences - consider comparing the requests using an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), it will give you more insights regarding what's going on under the hood.